# Save Form and render PDF

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf

some information why i have this situation:

> in my application, the user can change some data in a form and store
>   it. it also possible to generate a pdf with these changes. the user
>   had to save it, open the dialog again and can print now these changes.
>
> thats not a good way. i changed it to one action. now the user can
>   save the changes, form will be closed. if the user want to print the
>   changes, he just can push the print button, the changed data will be
>   saved, and after this the document will be printed.

I had 2 buttons in my form which will be send via ajax `remote: true`. 
One button is the default submit button to save the changes and close the form.

The other button `value=print` should save the changes, render the pdf, send it to the browser, and close the form.

this works pretty well. but looks not good to me.

**the form**

```
<%= form_for @product, remote: true do |f| %>
  <!-- some boring fields -->
  <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-print" type="submit" value="pdf" name="print"></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><%=t('forms.close')%></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><%=t('forms.save')%></button>
<% end %>
```

there you can see the both submit buttons.

**the controller actions**

```
def show
  # just generate the pdf and render it to browser
  # render_pdf will perform the send_file method with default :attachment
  render_pdf PdfEngine.render params
end

def update
  @product = Product.find params[:id]
  # do the update logic
  render :create 
end
```

**the partial create.js.erb**

```
<% if params[:print] %>
  location.href='<%=product_path(@product)%>'
<% else %>
  // do some blinky stuff
  // close the form and so one
<% end %>
```

is there a better way to store the and to store and render pdf?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways you could handle this.

1) generate the pdf, save it in your filesytem, and give the user a link to download the pdf.

2) generate the pdf, save it in a tmp location, and use send_file to send it directly to the user (making a "Save file" dialog open in their browser).

It's not clear to me which of these you are doing at the moment. Does render_pdf send the file back to the user, or does it load the file in their browser, or do something else?

I think your question is a bit too vague and open-ended:  it would be better for you to choose what you want to happen and then get help making that happen.

**EDIT**:
A nicer way to handle this is to have the `show` action display some product info on the page, in the normal way, for html requests, and to return a pdf of the product info for pdf requests.  ie

```
def show
  @product = Product.find params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #default is to render the show template, let it do that
    format.pdf do 
      render_pdf PdfEngine.render params #not sure exactly what this requires from params
    end
  end
end
```

You will need to do this in your config, if you haven't already

```
#in config/initializers/mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf
```

Now, you can have a regular show page which shows info about the product, and have a link to the pdf on it:

```
<%= link_to "Download PDF", product_path(@product, :format => "pdf") %>
```

Also i would have your create action,  if successful, redirect to the show page since this is the normal behaviour:

```
def update
  @product = Product.find params[:id]
  @updated = @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
  if @updated 
    redirect_to product_path(@product)
  else
    render :action => "edit" #or whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: i've added more information. actually i send the pdf document to the browser, and close the form. it works. but i think, there must be a better way to do this

Comment: the `redirect_to` want be working. its an ajax request. the show method just perform the pdf. nothing more. i dont need it for html output. the mime type is allready registered. the redirect will be performed behind the scenes, so nothing will be happened. it's a little bit complicated i think

Comment: Ah, if it's a remote action (ie ajax) then a nice way to handle it would be to render out a partial which has a link to the document, and use the result to replace a div on the page: so after the upload their document link appears on the page.

Comment: thats not really an option, because of the user experience. the user just want to print and could be confused if the dialog is closed, and a link to click to download the pdf. he want, change, save and generate the pdf. my solution works but i didn't like it. it feels so bad :) thank you for your time to improve this (imho codesmell)